# Is operator $(Tc)(t) = \sum_{1 \le n} c_n t^n$ from $l^1$ to $C[0,1]$ compact?

Tags: functional-analysis, compact-operators

I found that it is bounded, but have no idea how to prove it being compact. For $c_n=1/n!$ it has equidistant continuity, for $c_n = (-1)^n/(2n)!$ also, but how to prove it in general way? Please, give me an advice

Comment: n is natural number

Comment: No, $c = (c_n)_{1 \le n} \in l^1$

Comment: $c_1 t + c_2 t^2 + ... + c_i t^î + ...$

Comment: If you modify the operator to $(Tc)(t)=\sum a_nc_nt^n$ for a fixed sequence  $a_n\to 0,$ then you gain compactness.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$T$ is not compact since the image of the bounded sequence $(c(k))_k$ in $\ell^1$ defined by $c(k)_n=\delta_{k,n}$ is the sequence $(t^k)_k$ in $C[0,1],$ which has no uniformly convergent subsequence, its pointwise limit being discontinuous.